# What is the equivalent in English for 移步？

Tags: meaning-in-context

Literally, this means striding or walking, but it seems a polite term to urge people to move, e.g., 请移步到餐厅用膳, shall we say "Please walk to the dining room for your meal?" It sounds very awkward, because unless there is more than one mode of movement(as in an airport you can either walk or take a bus to get to the aeroplane), walk should not be mentioned or even stressed here.

Comment: the word 移步 is unnecessary. and in bus station/airport, it should be removed to save spaces.

Comment: @DanielYeung As in the cases you mentioned, most of the times there are simply signs without words as the signs you see attached to the toilet of the same facilities. But what I am talking about is not  how to save spaces or whether it is necessary or not for its existence in an expression.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, by saying "移步", there is nothing implied here and it's just a polite term. It simply makes sense by removing 移步 from the sentence. 请到餐厅用膳。

Personally, I don't think it's a good usage of 移步 in the context. It's kind of redundant.

Comment: Of course, I know the meaning and that the wording could be more concise, but turned out it is a real case I experienced, and the phrase was actually used by the host of a conference when he told the participant to have dinner. Oriental cultures have their own characteristics, that are my point of concern here.

Comment: Well, you can't control anyone would possible use it in a real practice. I would not feel very comfortable with the sentence, because the speaker tends to be too polite, which is not necessary most of time.  Sometimes, even with a wrong sentence, you would have to accept it unless you could not even understand it. What should I do when someone tried to speak in their own dialects which I totally can not understand?

Comment: You seem to have been distracted by yourself to another matter, which I think you may open a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

The term 移步 is related to an formal expression "请移玉步". It literally  means "please move your noble feet" (asking a noble to move his feet is ground for apologizing). It is a polite phrase for asking someone to move from his current location to a new one.

请**移步**到餐厅用膳 means "Please **relocate** yourself to the dining room for your meal" (imply you are apologizing for the inconvenience)

Comment: +1 as you said "relocate". To apologize for the inconvenience in this case, people usually say "麻烦您请到餐厅用膳". Nowadays, people rarely use 移步 for this kind of purpose.